# Characterizations of real concave functions

Tags: real-analysis

What are some characterizations of concave functions of real functions of a single real variable?

In my problem the function will be strictly increasing so characterizations of that special case are of interest as well.

Answer (score 1):

One very important characterization is the *dual* characterization of concave (and convex) functions: every concave function $f$ is the minimum of all linear functions $\varphi$ such that $\varphi\geq f$.

You might also want to look up the [Fenchel conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate).

Answer (score 1):

A function $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $D$ is an interval, is concave if
$$f(ax_1+(1-a)x_2) \ge af(x_1) + (1-a)f(x_2)$$
for all $x_1,x_2 \in D$ and all $a \in (0,1)$.

A simple characterisation is that the *hypograph*
$$H(f) = \{(x,y): \> y \le f(x) \}$$
is a convex set.

If $f$ is differentiable, $f$ is concave if and only if
$$f(x) \le f(x_0) + (x-x_0)f^\prime(x_0)$$
for all $x,x_0 \in D$.

If $f$ is twice differentiable, $f$ is concave if and only if
$$f^{\prime\prime} (x) \le 0$$
for all $x \in D$.